# Use an existing GitHub repo in Huggingface spaces

Tags: github, huggingface, gradio

I have a github repo of an ML application, and I have set up a local demo for that using Gradio. I want to host this demo on Huggingface spaces, so I created a new space, but that initialised a new repository.

How do I make it use (or clone) an existing GitHub repo instead, since the repo has the app.py and requirements.txt file necessary to set-up.

I tried this - https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/spaces-github-actions

But after adding the huggingface space repo to the remote of the git repo on my machine and force pushing, I get this error:

```
Counting objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Writing objects: 100% (75/75), 14.63 MiB | 1.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 75 (delta 21), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: -------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: You are not authorized to push to this repo. 
remote: Make sure that you are properly logged in.
remote: -------------------------------------------------------------------------
To https://huggingface.co/spaces/mohit-raghavendra/gt-policy-bot
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://huggingface.co/spaces/mohit-raghavendra/gt-policy-bot'
```